# How can you receive gaze events when making a windowed HoloLens app using HoloToolKit

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, augmented-reality, hololens

I have tried to capture what the user focuses on with his/her gaze but I did not succeed. I have tried to listen for Focus and Pointer events, but the small white dot that is supposed to move to what you gaze at is not moving when I use the HoloLens. When I look at a button for example, no events are triggered while using the HoloLens. However, if I gaze at a button and make a click gesture, the click is being received.
I do not tick the "virtual reality supported" checkbox in the player settings as I need to run the app inside a window within the HoloLens.

Has anyone tried something similar and has some advice for me?

Comment: Have you gotten this to work with MRTKv2(https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/README.html)? It is an alternative to upgrade for HoloToolkit, and folks have been moving away from HoloToolKit for a bit now, so we strongly recommend that migrating your project to the latest version of MRTKv2.

Comment: We decided to work with the HoloToolkit as it was still in beta when we started working on our app. As the gazing feature is the last feature of the app that is missing, we will probably not change to MRTKv2. But it must have worked in HoloToolkit already, has it not?

Comment: @TeaDrinkerJoe May I ask what the target version of HoloLens? HL1 or 2? HoloToolkit is very old, and was replaced by MRTK v1 almost 2 years ago. But if you are on v1, you can take a look at this MRA sample that shows how to implement gaze: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms-210 If you want to go further or already working for HL2, the MRTKv2 is the best choice. Base on our test result, it works as you expected.

Comment: It is used for HL1. Pretty sure I have already seen that explanation and tried this and that, but I'll try again. Thanks for answering.